# Стоит ли использовать ванильный email backend на django или нет?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

К проекту на джанго прикручен djoser и придется, по мимо рассылки JWT токенов при регистрации / сбросе паролей и изменении логина пользователя, рассылать новости (или какую ни будь спам рассылку), так же пользователи могут вступать в группы и новости из этих групп также придется рассылать по почтам и т.д. и т.п. Почтой на платформе будет заниматься Celery и вопрос такой: какие решения лучше использовать для отправки рассылок и почему.
Спасибо за внимание.

ЗЫ. Когда-то я слышал что ванильный СМТП джанги не справляется с небольшими нагрузками и вешает всю платформу.